# Fix html table width by modify style

Tags: c#, regex

Change html table style to width:100%

Hello everyone,

I try to fix html widh=100% by replace it style by regex expression and ignore the other syle
i want to replace
**style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1pt solid windowtext;height:457px;width:1077px;"**
by
**style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1pt solid windowtext;height:457px;width:100%;"**

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
string html = "<div style=\"border-collapse:collapse;border:1pt solid windowtext;height:457px;width:1077px;\"></div>";

string updatedHtml = Regex.Replace(html, @"(style=""[^""]*?\bwidth:)\d+px(.*?;"")", "$1100%$2");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Raj, but this replaced the other style and only keep width

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be regex? This seems like a very explicit replace operation.

Also, I wouldn't reccomended either, I'd personally load the html with a library suited for the task, then traverse it with Xpath.

The `HtmlAgiltyPack` NuGet package would be helpful here

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var xpath = "// *[contains(@style, 'border-collapse:collapse;border:1pt solid windowtext;height:457px;width:1077px;')]";

var elements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
if (elements != null)
{
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        var styleAttribute = element.Attributes["style"];
        if (styleAttribute != null)
        {
            styleAttribute.Value = styleAttribute.Value.Replace("width:1077px", "width:100%");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it? It would help the community to have that here.

Comment: with your above code snipet i replace  `code` styleAttribute.Value = styleAttribute.Value.Replace("width:1077px", "width:100%"); `code` by `code` styleAttribute.Value = styleAttribute.Value.Substring(0, styleAttribute.Value.IndexOf("width:")) + "width:100%";`code`

Comment: If you used my solution otherwise, could you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to replace the width attribute of the style attribute in your HTML code:

```
string input = "<td style=\"border-collapse:collapse;border:1pt solid windowtext;height:457px;width:1077px;\"></td>";
string pattern = @"(style\s*=\s*"")[^""]*(width\s*:\s*)(\d+)(px;)";
string replacement = "$1$2100%;";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: Thanks @52414A, but i want to keep other style

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how specific of a match is needed.  And, how much the CSS properties differ.

You can just use the entire *style* attribute text, and utilize the pattern syntax at the *width* property.

```
style=""border-collapse:collapse;border:1pt solid windowtext;height:457px;width:([^;]+);""
```

Or, if a more universal match is required, you can just provide the ordered text, statically.

```
style=""border-collapse:.+?;border:.+?;height:.+?;width:([^;]+);""
```

Then, just use replace group 1 with, *"100%"*.